# how can i get transitions on css to work checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am trying to add a transition effect to an element on my website. This element is set to display:none, but is set to display:block when a checkbox is clicked (the checkbox is a separate element). What i want to do is make it so that when the checkbox is checked, the element gets set to display:block, and also shows a transition, instead of it popping up. Here is my code:

```css
.category-text {
  width: 82%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-family: 'Burbank', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #F4D03F;
}

.desc-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 84.4%;
  width: 73px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Burbank', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  border: solid #ffffff 2px;
}

#toggle-1 {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .category-description {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
  <label class="desc-toggle" for="toggle-1">Description</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <div class="category-description">
    <p class="category-text">text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why is the checkbox set to `display: none`?

Comment: The checkbox is set to display:none for visual purposes. i did <label class="desc-toggle for="toggle-1>Description</label> and then set #toggle-1 to display: none. This turns the text "description" into the checkbox

Comment: Your css in the snippet is missing the class that hides the text initially, just a heads up. As for the effect you're looking for you can't add transition to display:none; when changing to display:block;. I would suggest using the visibility property or transitioning height or width.

Comment: My goal was to make the height ease-in when the checkbox sets the element to display:block. Maybe that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, a property is *animatable* if its value can be continuously transitioned from one value to another over a determined period of time.

`display` property is **not** animatable. The browser cannot technically determine values between two values of `display` (i.e: an element can't be half way betwen `display:none` and `display:block`).

What you want to do instead is `display` the element at all times and transition it from an "*invisible*" state (in which it doesn't interfere with other elements at all) to a "*visible*" state, in which it is rendered as requested.

In order to animate a property, it has to have an initial value that gets changed to another value based on some condition (in your case `input:checked ~`). Instead of instantly changing between values, the browser will perform a gradual transition, according to `animation` properties of the animated `property`.

Example:

```css
.category-text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #F4D03F;
}

.desc-toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle-1 {
  display: none;
}

.category-description {
  height: 0px;                         /* we start animation from 0px */
  overflow: hidden;                    /* without this the contents will be 
                                        * visible regardless of height */
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in;     /* transition has to be defined on base state of element */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;           /* make transition easier to observe */
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .category-description {
  height: 100px;                       /* change height when input is checked */
}
```

```html
<label class="desc-toggle" for="toggle-1">Description</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div class="category-description">
  <p class="category-text">text</p>
</div>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
```

A few points to note:

- the `transition` has to be defined on the more general selector; If you only define inside on `input:checked ~ *` state, your element will only have a transition when following a checked input and **will not have one** when the `input` is not checked (hence, it will not animate when the `input` is unchecked).
- the `transition` has to be made between two animatable values (most browsers cannot animate from some value to `auto` or `initial`, even though those values could be calculated by browser and translated into a physical value). However, libraries such as `velocity.js` can help with that (they do the calculation for you and request the browser to animate between the actual values).

Answer (score 1):

I made a new snippet to unclutter the code a bit, is this the effect you're going for?

```css
.content {
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  transition: max-height .3s ease-in-out;
}
#check {
  display: none;
}
#check:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<label id="click" for="check">Click Me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<div class="content"></div>
```